# Chat-migrated comments: "Discussion between ..."

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

While it is not listed in the [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), there seems to be a new feature which allows migrating longer comment threads to chat. Or I suddenly got more chatty, I remarked it today twice, and never before.

The feature creates new chat rooms with the title *Discussion between ‹userA› and ‹userB›*. This is a bit problematic, as this screenshot shows:

[image: chat screenshot: 6 times "Discussion between ..."]

1. The overview shows neither the question/answer from which this originated, nor the user names involved - one has to hover the mouse to get this information, and find the right chat room one is interested in.
2. The title implies that this is a two-person chat, no one else is invited. Often discussions on answers could profit from an outsider perspective.

Could we find some other title for these migrated discussions? Use a part of the question title, perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried editing the room info?

Comment: On a related note, does this scale?  And how long do the rooms last?  Are they a permanent record, or do they get purged periodically?

Comment: @random: No, but I'm more thinking about the auto-generated name, without any user interaction.

Comment: The automatically generated name will only have meaning if the participants give it one. Which means it has to be edited, unless the title of the original posted question is somehow incorporated.  It looks like the title of the room is extremely limited in the number of characters you can practically use.

Comment: @Robert: I think it is the [same policy as with any room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention): *A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users. Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen.*

Comment: @Robert: normal users can't edit the name of the room ... until they are made owners. See my next question: [Give chat-rooms imported from comments an owner (or two)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99138/give-chat-rooms-imported-from-comments-an-owner-or-two)