# Give chat-rooms imported from comments an owner (or two)

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

[I already complained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96914/chat-migrated-comments-discussion-between) about the fact that the chat rooms created from moving a comment-discussion to chat have a bad name ("Discussion between ...").

In the comments there Robert Harvey said:

> The automatically generated name will only have meaning if the participants give it one.
> Which means it has to be edited, unless the title of the original posted question is
> somehow incorporated.

I interpreted this as the participants could rename the chat room at will. Today I finally [started such a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1673/discussion-between-palo-ebermann-and-martin-klosi), and found out that **I'm not able to rename the room**. It seems that only room owners can rename a room, and these automatically-generated rooms have no owner (the list of owners is empty).

So here my request:

- As the system seems to be able to derive who should be frequenting the chat room (it is putting these names in the title line), **make those people also *owners* to the chat room**, so they can give it a nice title. If two owners is too complicated, at least the user which clicked the "move to chat" link.

Alternatively, allow anyone (or at least these people) to edit the chat room name.

---

Related:

- [Chat clean up & owner rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80205/chat-clean-up-owner-rules/80208#80208) assigns ownership to active users - but I will likely not that active in a question-specific chat room that I will be assigned owner.
- Neal's question [Create comment-spawned chatrooms for the post, not for the users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98926/create-comment-spawned-chatrooms-for-the-question-not-for-the-users) takes the same problem from another angle.

Comment: related and/or duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98926/create-comment-spawned-chatrooms-for-the-question-not-for-the-users

Comment: @Neal: Yeah, either one would be a solution for the problem, with different nuances.