# How do you become an owner of an ownerless chatroom?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, ownership

For example the rooms created from a post are **ownerless**.

How does one become the owner of such a room, or any other room that has no owner?

---

*Related* but not the same: [Give chat-rooms imported from comments an owner (or two)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99138/241700)

Comment: Then who is the owner? Who can move anything anywhere? Or change the title of the chat room?

Comment: Nobody, nobody, and nobody, respectively.

Comment: What was the 2nd one again?

Comment: Moderators can do anything, can't they? Even if the option isn't there, I think the system will allow the AJAX call to add a new owner from a moderator. Obviously I can't find out for you.

Comment: Related as well (linked as related to other related post): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98926/create-comment-spawned-chatrooms-for-the-post-not-for-the-users

Answer (score 7):

### Method A

1. Talk a lot in said room.
2. Wait.
3. Automatically get added as an owner, since no more owners are active.

---

### Method B

1. Find a user who has a diamond beside their name. If you're in chat, look for a blue nametag.
2. Ask them to add you.
3. If you are not a room owner and you are not banned for annoying the mods and you want to take the risk of being banned for annoying another mod, go to step 1.

---

### Method C

1. Become elected to community moderator OR get hired at Stack Exchange.
2. Add yourself.

Comment: But certain rooms have **no owners** whatsoever. It is not a case of an owner being non-active.

Comment: But of course if no owners *are*, then no owners *are active*. It has nothing to do with inactive owners.

Comment: I think you should add a max number of retries to method B.

Comment: @Servy I added an additional break condition that should be satisfactory.

Comment: @KendallFrey Looks good.